# PayPal Error - This transaction cannot be processed, please pay with another card

Tags: paypal

Customer's trying to purchase via PayPal are experiencing problems accessing the PayPal website from our website.

They click to pay via PayPal to pay by Card they see this error:

"This transaction cannot be processed, please pay with another card. "

Has anyone else had this problem? and is there a fix? thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming as posted and is more likely a vendor/product support question. On the surface it simply looks like a standard failed card (invalid, no funds, etc.) message, and as such there is no "fix" other than what is already stated - _"please pay with another card"_

Comment: Do not close this please. I have similar issues with the sandbox mode before I am even allowed to enter any card details. +1